# Как правильно дополнить опциями команду для bash

Tags: bash, wget

есть код `$ cat файл | while read n l; do wget -O $n $l; done`
подскажите как в этом коде правильно дополнить программу wget опциями:

`-P /folder` и `-t 2`

Пробовал вставить сразу после wget , вот так: `$ cat файл | while read n l; do wget -t 2 -P /folder -O $n $l; done` , но добавленные опции не сработали.

Спасибо

Comment: что значит "ничего не вышло"?

Comment: добавленные опции не сработали

Comment: `-P /folder` немного смущает - похоже Вы пытаетесь сохранять прямо в корень (это уже вызывает подозрения), но может просто решили скрыть настоящий путь. Как поняли, что -t не сработал... если сервер работает хорошо, то этот параметр не протестить.

Comment: Да, я упростил , пытаюсь сохранить не в корень,

Comment: по поводу -t 2 вы правы, сейчас внимательней проверил , эта опциия работает, а вот с директорией пока не ясно

Comment: думаю, вторая также работает. Просто либо каталог не создан, либо прав на него нет, либо каталог не там.

Comment: Почему бы не перейти на более мощный и понятный `lftp`?